# If noseX is on cnvSection[i], draw img[i] on the canvas

Tags: javascript, p5.js, ml5.js

I'm making a sketch with the p5.js library and ml5's poseNet. I have the variable `noseX` — which indicates the x-coordinate position of the nose on the canvas — and a preloaded array of 60 images. I would like to vertically divide the canvas into 60 sections. For each `cnvSection` `noseX` is on, I want the image `img[i]` corresponding to that `cnvSection[i]` to to be drawn on the canvas.

So basically if `noseX` is on `cnvSection[5]`, draw `img[5]` on the canvas etc.

Here's my function, at the moment I have only been able to draw the vertical lines indicating the canvas sections.

```
let cnvWidth = 1440;
let cnvHeight = 900;

function nosePosition() {

  let sectionWidth = cnvWidth / 60;
  let cnvSection = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < cnvWidth; i = i + sectionWidth) {
    line(i, 0, i, cnvHeight);
  }
}
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
noseX = 50;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(700, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(220);
  nosePosition();
  fill('red');
  ellipse(noseX, height / 2, 6);
}

function nosePosition() {
  let sectionWidth = width / 60;
  for (let i = 0; i < width; i += sectionWidth) {
    line(i, 0, i, height);
  }
  const noseSection = floor(noseX / sectionWidth);
  rect(noseSection * sectionWidth, 0, sectionWidth, height);
}
```

To simplify I use a hardcoded x value for the nose. In your case that would come from ml5 posenet. You don't need the sections in an array. You can simlpy calculate in which section the nose currently is and then draw the image accordingly. I am drawing a rect - again, to simplify the example.

Maybe copy and paste this into the p5 web editor and play around with the `noseX` value and see if that works for you.

Comment: Hi @Nils ! Thanks for answering. How do I then draw the array of images efficiently? In the array, every image corresponds with a section — depending on the x position of the nose (which section the nose is on), the corresponding image should appear.

Comment: Never mind! I have figured it out — thanks to your advice, many thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is not necessary anymore but: ```image(img, x, y, [width], [height])``` You can just use that in the same way I draw the rectangle and use the calculated noseSection as index at which to access the image array. ```image(arrayOfImg[noseSection], noseSection * sectionWidth, 0, sectionWidth, height) ```